# How to refresh the UITableViewController view?

Tags: ios, swift3

I am making a web service call to retrieve a list of research articles based on a search term.  When my app started, the table view is empty. I get that bit.  But once I have made a successful web service call and populate by data source with my custom objects, I do not know how to trigger the UITableViewDataSource protocol's required methods to refresh my table view.  Please can someone advise?

```
 let articleLibrary = ArticleLibrary()
 ......
 switch listOfArticlesStatus{
      case let .failure("main fail"):
      print("main fail")
      case let .success(list):
      // LIST OF ARTICLES SUCCESSFULLY RETRIEVED!
      // Assign articles to ArticleLibrary
      self.articleLibrary.allArticles = list
      var numRows = list.count

              // HOW DO I REFRESH THE TABLEVIEW FROM HERE? OR DO I?



      default:
      break
      }


 // Sets how many rows in the table view to display
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let numRows = self.articleLibrary.allArticles.count
    if numRows != nil {
        print("numRows: \(numRows)")
        return numRows
    }else{
        print("numRows: \(numRows)")
        return 0;
    }
}

// Create cells to populate table
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Create instance of UITableViewCell
    let cell = UITableViewCell.init(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "UITableViewCell")
    let item = articleLibrary.allArticles[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = item.title
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = item.pmid

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> yourTableView.reloadData()

call this method. This method will reload whole table.
But if you want to reload only visible cells then call this method.

> ```
> tableView.reloadRows(at:tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows!, with:     .none)
> ```

Answer (score 2):

```
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

This should do the job.

Answer (score 2):

Use `self.tableView.reloadData()` after updating datasource.

Answer (score 1):

use `self.tableView.reloadData()` to refresh your table .

Answer (score 1):

`self.tableView.reloadData()` is enough for normal cases. If you are inside a closure or background thread, you need to reload your `tableView` within main block like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```